# how to make draggable transparent inside a Div

Tags: jquery, draggable

I want to make my draggable transparent this code does not work

```
$("#draggable").draggable({draggableClass:'transparent'});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ opacity: 0});
```

Comment: it does not work I want the draggable background to be transparent this is my site http://amp.site88.net/

Comment: how can I get rid of the Widget it takes a lot of space I want to keep the draggable part

Comment: I really don't know... I just had a quick read in the docs... the default example is using a plain div... so that should get you started